# Can AVSpeechSynthesizer solve speech recognition in background?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, avspeechsynthesizer, apple-speech

unfortunately, i didn't find any solution to recognize user speech in background, I just yesterday read about AVSpeechSynthesizer. sorry i didn't read a lot about AVSpeechSynthesizer and I should submit my project on Thursday. really I need to solve this problem, so any one know about AVSpeechSynthesizer is it possiable to help me when I want to recognize user voice if he/she say specified word? for example say "hello" in background.

thank you for your time.

Comment: `AVSpeechSynthesizer` does speech synthesis, not recognition, so it's unlikely it can recognize speech at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very specifically-designed interactions you can implement with `SiriKit`. Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/)

Besides what is offered there, I do not think there is anything else that would allow you to monitor the microphone and detect speech while your app is in background.